# Flutter : How to specify a device id in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to select a device id in flutter run?

> please specify a device with the '-d ' flag, or use '-d all'
>   to act on all devices

```
iPhone 6      • 54XXXXXX35130ebefd38f • ios • iOS 10.3.3
iPhone 7 Plus • BA8CXXXXXXD0-577D675d • ios • iOS 11.2 (simulator)
```

Answer (score 59):

Simply use

```
flutter run -d iPhone 6
```

For me this also works fine

```
flutter run -d BA8CXXXXXXD0-577D675d
```

Comment: Can we do multiple devices?

Comment: For Android you have to reveal the device ID of the emulator using `adb devices`.

Answer (score 32):

```
flutter run -d "Iphone 6"
```

Test on MacOS High Sierra (

Answer (score 11):

use the command on the terminal of android studio -

```
#flutter run -d "device name or id"
```

if the device name contains blank space it throws an error, so using device ID is better...

for example in my case the device ID was-

```
#flutter run -d 590******140
```

and it worked :)

Comment: The Android emulator device name `flutter_emulator` does not work.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to open on simulator, try this:

1. Get all devices available `xcrun simctl list`
   Output can be like this

   ```
   == Devices ==
   -- iOS 13.5 --
   iPhone 8 (21DB8D2B-F71B-4D91-AB56-FD64A20CEEE7) (Shutdown)
   iPhone 8 Plus (D4AA1ABE-D40B-437D-9373-9AF89F2A4951) (Shutdown)
   iPhone 11 (44CE162D-D077-4165-BE44-33DE723FDBAB) (Shutdown)
   ```
2. Set the desired device `xcrun simctl boot 21DB****` ( For iPhone 8)
3. Run flutter `flutter run`

If no open any simulator, run `open -a Simulator`