# can't run flutter app on physical android device

Tags: android, flutter

I created a flutter app but couldn't run it on a physical android phone, i didn't try the emulator since it totally slows my computer, i only have i5 cpu 1.5-1.7 ghz nd 4gb ram most of it is occupied by windows system, here's the error message, i also wanna say that i've already accepted all the license agreements of the SDK, so i don't think that's the problem

error message:

[image]

Comment: Execute `flutter devices` command. What is your output?

Comment: You may need to specify your device => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684621/flutter-how-to-specify-a-device-id-in-flutter

Comment: @daddygames I ran the command nd everything went well, it detects my phone name, android version....

Comment: You can always try some simple things like revoking and re-granting the USB debugging rights, trying a different phone or cable, to see where the problem lies

Comment: @fravolt it didn't work, can u plz upvote the question so many people can see it?

Comment: @credirgam Can you edit your question to include the image in the post instead of in a link? It makes it easier for people to help. and helps preserve the post for those who come back to it later in case the image is taken down from wherever you are hosting it.

Comment: @developerextraordinare i'd like to but i don't know how to do this, i'm new to this site

Comment: i edited the post, i added that i've already accepted the flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: It would be more understandable if you post the output of `flutter doctor -v`  too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to Gradle, this is usually due to corrupt or incomplete Gradle setup
Go to the root directory and **locate the hidden .gradle folder and delete it**.

**For mac users**,

open the terminal and execute

```
cd ~
rm -rf .gradle
```

and then run your app connected to an Android emulator or device, don't cancel and make sure to have have a stable internet connection, this will download fresh Gradle

**For Windows**,

Go to the root directory C:\Users\YourUser and locate the hidden .gradle folder and delete it.
and then run your app connected to an Android emulator or device, don't cancel and make have a stable internet connection, this will download fresh Gradle

If all of the above didnt worked then try running `flutter clean` and `flutter create .` and finally `flutter run`.

If the problem persists, then you need to provide your `flutter doctor -v` and `flutter run --verbose` logs.